# How to enumerate editors and their locations in Intellij Platform SDK?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I have the following example layout on screen

[image]

How to enumerate these editors and their locations from within Plugin code?

Any hints please. Can't understand where to dig...

---

The following code

```
IdeFrame[] ideFrames = windowManager.getAllProjectFrames();
```

return only one entry

[image]

Comment: I'd recommend you ask the IntelliJ team directly at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200366979-IntelliJ-IDEA-Open-API-and-Plugin-Development .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find all active/open editors by using the `selectedEditors` property of the `FileEditorManager`, and then ask each editor for their [location on screen](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360009434019-How-to-get-position-and-size-of-project-editor-):

```kotlin
FileEditorManager.getInstance(project).selectedEditors.associateWith {
    it.component.locationOnScreen
}
```

In Java that could be something like

```java
Editor[] editors = FileEditorManager.getInstance(project).getSelectedEditors()
Point[] locations = editors.stream()
    .map(editor -> editor.getComponent().getLocationOnScreen())
    .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

(It probably depends on your context and what you want to do with it how you'd implement this, but you get the idea.)